Does changing Task reference to Task.CompletedTask make sense in context of GC and reference counting?
Considering I have simple class, that I just want to initialize (or do some task once in a lifetime of the object). Does switching the reference to Task.Completed after all is done change anything, considering GC?
    public class EmployeesAtPremisesAfterWork
    {

        private ConcurrentHashSet<int> isAtPremisesAfterWork = new ConcurrentHashSet<int>();
        public Task WaitUntilInitialized;

        public EmployeesAtPremisesAfterWork(SomeInitializationHelper helper)
        {
            WaitUntilInitialized = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var attachedValues = await helper.GetEmployeeAttachedValues();

                isAtPremisesAfterWork.AddRange(attachedValues.AtPremisesAfterWork);

                WaitUntilInitialized = Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        }
    }

I was just curious, since I still am not really sure about things GC related. Does Task keep reference to its context, after it is finished, or does it release it?

.NET doesn't use reference counting. Each garbage collection operation discovers instances.
If you question is "too many references hurt GC performance?", the answer is "it might". But you need to measure it to know for sure.
What are you expecting the outcome of your code to be? It's just assigning a completed task to field that will have a that task it was assigned completed.
If you are adding the WaitUntilInitialized field just for the purpose of this hack, than you are increasing the size of your class and the number of instances the GC has to check for reachability.
If you are using that field, chances are, the calling code has already grabbed the reference to the Task returned by Task.Run.

I have some parts of code, that needs to be run asynchronously, but are kind of needed for initialization of this asp.net singleton. What I was trying to do was to await WaitUntilInitialized in any task, that would be working with EmployeesAtPremisesAfterWork class, to be sure, it is properly initialized.
What I was trying to ask, was that if I used some helper class and passed it to the context of the Initialization task, if the GC would be able to collect it, after the task ends, or if keeping the reference to the task would prohibit GC to do it.

If the object is not reachable, the GC will collect it.

So my question is. Should I change reference of my task to Task.CompletedTask, or can I leave it as is? Does the Task object keep reference to the context, that was supplied to it, or does it release it after it ends and keeps reference only to the result? (not in this case, this one does not return result).

Basically, would this:
        WaitUntilInitialized = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var attachedValues = await helper.GetEmployeeAttachedValues();

            isAtPremisesAfterWork.AddRange(attachedValues.AtPremisesAfterWork);

            //delete line: WaitUntilInitialized = Task.CompletedTask;
        });

make helper object collectible for GC after the task ends?

Can you show the code that is awaiting WaitUntilInitialized?

Consider having public method in the original class that goes like this:
public bool IsAtPremisesAfterWork(int id) => isAtPremisesAfterWork.Contains(id);
Then the caller would be a controller looking something like this:
`class EmployeeLocationController
{
public EmployeeLocationController(EmployeesAtPremisesAfterWork atPremises)
{
//assign to field
}
[HttpGet]  
public Task<bool> IsAtPremises(int id)  
{  
    await atPremises.WaitUntilInitialized;  
    return atPremises.IsAtPremisesAfterWork(id);  
}  

}`

Have you tied/tested it?
